# Selenium locate span bind element

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium/Java

Below is the HTML/JavaScript code.

```
<span j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.type', element)">Yes</span>
```

In automated test case how to locate and click on 'Yes' using Selenium and Java?

Comment: If this element is not unique on the page, you will need to provide more HTML so that we can find a solution that will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `j:bind` attribute

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[j:bind='appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.type', element)'][text()='Yes']")).click();
```

Or using `contains`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(j:bind, 'user.subscription.type'][contains(text(), 'Yes')]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks.There are many elements on the webpage like                                  <span j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.type', element)">Yes</span>                                                                                <span j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.active', element)">Yes</span>

Comment: @SUM does `j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.type', element)"` unique?

Comment: One div on web page has j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.type', element)"> Yes      </span>                                  j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.type', element)"> Maybe     </span>                                                                                                                                                                                                             Another div has j:bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.active', element)">Yes</span>                     :bind=“appProp.UserFor(‘user.subscription.active', element)">Maybe</span>

Answer (score 0):

Use following xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Yes')]")).click();
```